# Neutralizador de gênero em C!

Tags: c

Sou iniciante na área de programação e peguei alguns exercícios básicos para treinar minha lóg. de prog. em C. E uma dessas questões era para desenvolver um programa que neutralizasse o gênero das palavras inseridas, como: meninas -> meninxs ; negros -> negrxs.
Já tenho um pseudo-código montado e deixarei ele e o enunciado linkados aqui no corpo (pelo pastebin.com) no entanto, minha dificuldade mesmo é criar uma variável para fazer essa neutralidade.
Desde já agradeço.

Obs.: isso não tem viés político algum, é apenas algo didático e de aluno para aluno. Agradeço a compreensão.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//o problema já começa na declaração de variáveis, nao sei se o certo seria uma declaração em "char" mas enfim...

char genero, palavra;
     genero = x;
     palavra = a, o;

//entrada

    printf("Os pesquisadores da universidade recebem mal");

//aqui já entraria a suposta variável para neutralizar os gêneros das palavras
//ação a ser executada...

    printf("Xs pesquisadorxs dx universidadx recebem mal");

//aqui se repetiriam as 3 (três) frases

return 0;
```

**Enunciado**:

Você trabalha para o jornal ----- -----, troque todos os marcadores
de gênero para a letra X.

Entrada

```
os pesquisadores da universidade recebem mal
os alunos de escola particular sao privilegiados
```

Saída

```
xs pesquisadorxs dx universidadx recebem mal
xs alunxs dx escola particular sxx privilegiadxs
```

Comment: Jovem, primeiramente, use as tags de forma correta, C e C# são coisas completamente diferentes. Também nunca coloque seu código em fontes externas, isso dificulta o acesso às pessoas que têm bloqueios para alguns domínios e, além disso, dificulta a leitura da pergunta, ninguém quer ter que acessar 3 links diferentes para tentar escrever uma resposta.

Comment: Leia algum tutorial básico sobre declaração e atribuição de variáveis em C. Com genero = x; você está atribuindo o conteúdo da variável x à variável gênero, talvez você quisesse fazer: genero = 'x'; (atribuir a constante 'x' à variável genero).

Comment: Por que em seu exemplo a letra 'e', do final de universidade, é trocada por 'x'?

Comment: LINQ : Valeu, sou novato aqui e suas dicas foram muito úteis.                           anonimo1: Valeu, vou tentar sua sugestão.                                                              anonimo2: também achei bizarro, mas é feito de aluno para aluno, apenas para fins didáticos então creio que não interfira muito.

Comment: Só com um parser para fazer o que você quer. Para criar um parser você vai ter que construir um analisador léxico com o lex(ou flex)  mais um analisador sintático criado com o yacc(ou bison) que juntos irão atuar sobre o texto com base em um dicionário digital da linguá portuguesa para que depois que você apensar um token **gramatical**(não um token sintático) a todas as palavras ai sim pode decidir quais palavras podem ou não ter o gênero neutralizado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde @MaSanTM,

Primeiramente: Essa não é uma questão tão simples quanto parece.

Para nós, humanos, é muito simples e fácil identificar onde por ou não o 'x' para neutralizar os gêneros das palavras, mas o computador executa apenas instruções, então cabe a nós explicitar as regras e as exceções.

No exemplo:

"**A garota pegou na furadeira**"

neutralizando gêneros seria:

`"X garotx pegou na furadeira"`

porém a complexidade está na forma como passar as instruções para o computador.

- **Tentativa 1:**

"Computador, troque todas as letras 'o' e 'a' por 'x' "

Resultado:

`"X gxrxtx pegxu nx furxdeirx"`

Opa, já nos deparamos com o primeiro problema: Não são todas as letras 'o' e 'a' que devem ser substituídas, para que a leitura da frase não se torne um jogo de adivinhação. Além disso, temos palavras que tem gênero definido e não tem 'o' ou 'a', por exemplo: "professores". Nesse ponto já podemos perceber que apenas as letras 'o' e 'a' que estão no final de cada palavra precisam ser trocadas, mais precisamente nas duas últimas letras, que é onde se posicionam gramaticalmente a classificação dos gêneros das palavras, então vamos lá.

- **Tentativa 2:**

"Computador, troque as letras 'o','a' e ocasionalmente 'e', mas só as que tiverem nas duas últimas posições de cada palavra"

Resultado:

`"X garotx pegxu nx furadeirx"`

É um resultado melhor do que o anterior, mas ainda tem muitos problemas. "Furadeira" é uma palavra de gênero feminino, no entanto é um nome de objeto, então não entra da regra da escrita neutra, assim como "pegou" e "na".

- **Tentativa 3:**

  "Computador, troque as letras 'o', 'a' e ocasionalmente 'e' por 'x', em palavras que se relacionem com sujeitos, para neutralizar seus gêneros. como artigos e adjetivos, mas não troque se forem objetos, pois eles não tem gêneros"

Resultado:

`"X garotx pegou na furadeira"`

Perfeito, não? porém passar instruções pra um programa não é tão simples quanto dizer "Computador, faça isso". Para tornar a instrução acima legível para um computador teríamos que alimenta-lo com uma quantidade considerável de dados e regras.

Esse livro acima foi apenas pra abrir sua mente em relação a complexidade que alguns programas podem assumir. sou estudante de computação então acho importante te dar essa primeira noção, poque as vezes deixamos coisas passarem "batidas".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char string[100];
int i;

gets(string);

for(i=0;i<100;i++){

   if(string[i] == ' '){ //Checando se o caractere em questão é um espaço
       if(string[i- 1] == 'a' || string[i- 1] == 'o'){
           string[i- 1] = 'x';
       }else if(string[i- 2] == 'a' || string[i- 2] == 'o' || string[i- 2] == 'e'){
           string[i- 2] = 'x';
       }else{
           i++;
       }
   }
}

printf(string);

return 0;
}
```

Esse é um exemplo de código que fiz até a segunda tentativa, "Computador, substitua as letras 'o', 'a' e ocasionalmente 'e' no final das palavras".

Eu deixei um furo de lógica propositalmente, consegue descobrir qual é? não é nada tão complexo quanto os problemas que citei acima e pode te servir como exercício.

Espero que esse conhecimento lhe seja útil.

Bem vindx ao Stackoverflow e bons estudos!

Abraço!

Comment: De longe a sua resposta foi a que mais ajudou amigo, e agradeço muitíssimo. Os comentários à minha pergunta ajudaram também mas não com o que eu necessitava. Enfim, vendo sua resposta percebi que preciso estudar um pouco mais a linguagem C e focar em strings (já mexi com Java e era também minha maior dificuldade, estou iniciando agora na área). Mas desde já agradeço.